# Can I use Joomla's community builder as a form component?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla-community-builder

I was developing a website that allows people to enter records. at the time, cb was the best component for the job, the client was not clear if the records were a one time thing or not, so i opted for cb. problem is now the client wants the system to be able to allow a user to enter multiple records without overwriting the previous record, of which cb does not allow as it is more of a profile component and restarting the whole system would be a lot of work and myt take about 2 weeks as I have about ten different forms with multiple fields. is there a plugin or any other way that I can allow a user to have multiple records or registrations using the same credentials in community builder?

Comment: This is a good question. It might be better on the Joomla Stack Exchange website though. I suspect you'll need to redo those forms unfortunately.

Comment: Thanx Neil, il post the question there... I suspect I might have to redo the whole forms with another component but still need to have that as the final measure.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use some websites that provide a component creator to build the required

Try [jc-creator.com](https://jc-creator.com)